# How do I disable/adjust the behaviour of tab completion for specific functions in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Let's say that I've written a function, `Foo-Rab`, that uses a helper function, `Foo-Bar`, which has a very specific purpose and isn't intended to be used on its own. I've placed the code for these functions into my profile, such that I can type `Foo-` and hit tab to auto-complete their names. However, the first result is `Foo-Bar`, which I never intend to use in this way; I have to hit tab twice to get `Foo-Rab`, the function I actually want.

Ideally, I'd like to disable tab completion for `Foo-Bar` altogether. If that's not possible, how do get `Foo-Rab` to appear first, without changing the name of either function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [Private](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.1) function to hide your helper functions from your general shell - The syntax is helpfully `Function Private:MyFunction` or `$Private:Foo` for variables. Here's an example that defines both kinds:

```
# Create a function you can run directly
Function Do-Foo ($Foo) {

  $Private:Bar = $Foo+$Foo

  Write-Output "Top level Foo is $Foo"
  Write-Output "Top level Bar is $Bar"

  # Create a helper function
  Function Private:Do-Bar {
    Write-Output "Child Foo is $Foo"
    Write-Output "Child Bar is $Bar" # Can't be used since it was private
  }

  # Can be used by function Do-Foo, but not by you!
  Do-Bar
}
```

If you add this to your profile or just run it normally, you'll be able to tab-complete `Do-Foo` like normal, but you won't even be able to run `Do-Bar`:

```sh
PS C:\> Do-Foo -Foo 1
Top level Foo is 1
Top level Bar is 2
Child Foo is 1
Child Bar is 

PS C:\> Do-Bar
Do-Bar : The term 'Do-Bar' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, Function, ...
```

Success!

Other than that, the Powershell tab-complete function is simply alphabetical order by default. This can be changed with PSReadLine in newer versions of powershell:

```
# The default setting:
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Tab -Function TabCompleteNext
```

There's a lot of different built-in options, some I see that might interest you are `Complete`, `MenuComplete`, `PossibleCompletions`, or `ViTabCompleteNext`. I'm using PSReadLine version 2.2.0.

Comment: Thank you very much, private functions were exactly the type of solution I was looking for! It also never occurred to me that my helper functions should be inside of the primary function, I'd just been writing them each separately. Your tip regarding PSReadLine is also spot on, I've been using MenuComplete for the last week or so and I've found it much more convenient than the default.